# Useless result of Integrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, fourier-analysis

Considering a Fourier sine series, I calculate

```
int = Integrate[Log[1 + Sin[x]]*Sin[i*x], {x, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> i ∈ PositiveIntegers]
```

> `1/4 (-((2 E^(-(1/2) I i π))/i^2) + (2 E^((I i π)/2))/i^2 +  E^(-I i π)/i^2 - E^(I i π)/i^2 + ( 4 (E^((I i π)/2) - Cos[(i π)/2]) HurwitzLerchPhi[-1, 1,  1 - i])/i - ( 2 I (1 - E^(-I i π)) HurwitzLerchPhi[-I, 1, 1 - i])/i - ( 2 I LerchPhi[-I, 1, 1 + i])/i + ( 2 I E^(I i π) LerchPhi[-I, 1, 1 + i])/i - ( E^(-(1/2) I i π) (-1 + E^(I i π)) PolyGamma[0, 1 + i/2])/ i + (E^(-(1/2) I i π) (-1 + E^(I i π)) PolyGamma[0, ( 1 + i)/2])/i + ( 4 HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 3/2}, {2 - i/2, 2 + i/2}, 1] Sin[( i π)/2]^2)/(-4 i + i^3) - ( 2 HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1, 1}, {3/2 - i/2, 3/2 + i/2}, 1] Sin[ i π])/(-1 + i^2))`

Unfortunately, the result is useless in view of

```
Table[int, {i, 1, 5}]
```

> `{Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate, Indeterminate,  Indeterminate}`

and

```
Limit[int, i -> 3]
```

which returns the input.

It should be noticed that

```
Table[Integrate[Log[1 + Sin[x]]*Sin[i*x], {x, 0, Pi}], {i, 1, 5}]
```

results in `{-2 + π, 0, 1/9 (10 - 3 π), 0, -(46/75) + π/5}`.

Is there a workaround for the general case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a general formula for integrals, if you `TrigExpand` the integer multiples of `Sin[j x]` and integrate each summand alone.

Make use of the fact, that summands can be developed with a Binomial formula.

```
(tab = Table[(Sin[(j)*x] // TrigExpand), {j, 1, 11}]) // TableForm

(ta = Table[
Sum[(-1)^( (k - 1)/2) Binomial[n, k]*Cos[x]^(n - k) Sin[x]^k, {k, 
  1, n, 2}], {n, 1, 11}]) // TableForm
```

ta == tab yields `True`

```
int[n_, k_] = 
  Integrate[
   Log[1 + Sin[x]]*((-1)^( (k - 1)/2) Binomial[n, k]*Cos[x]^(n - k)
   Sin[x]^k), {x, 0, Pi}, 
     Assumptions -> 
 n \[Element] Integers && n > 0 && k \[Element] Integers && k > 0 &&
 1 <= k <= n]

(*     -(I I^-k ((-1)^k + (-1)^n) Binomial[n, k] Gamma[
 1/2 (1 - k + n)] (4 Gamma[2 + k/2] Gamma[2 + n/2] Gamma[(3 + n)/
    2] HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 3/2, 2 + k/2}, {5/2, 5/2 + n/2}, 
    1] + 3 Gamma[(5 + n)/
    2] (4 Gamma[1 + k/2] Gamma[2 + n/2] - (2 + n) Gamma[(1 + k)/
       2] Gamma[(3 + n)/
       2] (PolyGamma[0, 1 + n/2] - 
        PolyGamma[0, 1/2 (1 - k + n)]))))/(24 Gamma[
 2 + n/2] Gamma[(3 + n)/2] Gamma[(5 + n)/2])     *)

ta2 = Table[Sum[int[n, k], {k, 1, n, 2}], {n, 1, 11}] // 
  FullSimplify // Expand

(*     {-2 + \[Pi], 0, 10/9 - \[Pi]/3, 0, -(46/75) + \[Pi]/5, 0, 
334/735 - \[Pi]/7, 0, -(982/2835) + \[Pi]/9, 0, 
10942/38115 - \[Pi]/11}     *)

ta1 = Table[
  Integrate[Log[1 + Sin[x]]*Sin[(i)*x], {x, 0, Pi}], {i, 1, 11}] // 
  Expand
```

ta1 == ta2 yields `True`

Comment: +1. I need to think some time before accepting or not accepting it.

Answer (score 4):

Often Mathematica `Integrate` shows problems with `integer assumptions`.
As a workaround try

```
intEven[i_] := Integrate[Log[1 + Sin[x]]*Sin[(2 i )*x], {x, 0, Pi}]
Table[{2 i, intEven[i]}, {i, 1, 5}]
(*{{2, 0}, {4, 0}, {6, 0}, {8, 0}, {10, 0}}*)


intOdd[i_] := Integrate[Log[1 + Sin[x]]*Sin[(2 i-1 )*x], {x, 0, Pi}]
Table[{2 i - 1, intOdd[i]}, {i, 1, 5}]
(*{{1, -2 + \[Pi]}, {3,1/9 (10 - 3 \[Pi])}, {5, -(46/75) + \[Pi]/5}, {7,334/735 - \[Pi]/7}, {9, -(982/2835) + \[Pi]/9}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

The coefficients on `Pi` looks like `Sin[i π/2]/i`, and `FindSequenceFunction` can suggest the rational part:

```
a[i_] := a[i] = Integrate[Log[1 + Sin[x]]*Sin[i*x], {x, 0, Pi}];

seq = Table[a[i] - Sin[i π/2] π/i, {i, 1, 28, 2}] // Expand // FindSequenceFunction;
FullSimplify[seq[(i + 1)/2], i ∈ PositiveIntegers]
(* (I^(1 + i) i π + 2 (-1)^i (-1 + i LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + i/2]))/i^2 *)
```

Which simplifies to

```
Table[a[i] - (((-1 + (-1)^i) (-1 + i LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + i/2]))/i^2), {i, 18}] // Expand
(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: +1. I need to think some time before accepting or not accepting it.

Comment: Unfortunately, `N[(I^(1 + i) i \[Pi] + 2 (-1)^i (-1 + i* LerchPhi[-1, 1, 1 + i/2]))/
   i^2 /. i -> 4]` results in `-0.0284264 + 0.785398 I` so this is not it. BTW, I unsuccessfully tried `FindSequenceFunction`